# How does /proc/cpuinfo detect the CPU model?

Tags: linux-kernel

I have a server which displays the following information in `dmidecode` output for CPU:

```
Handle 0x000D, DMI type 4, 35 bytes                            
Processor Information          
        Socket Designation: CPU 1                              
        Type: Central Processor                                
        Family: Xeon           
        Manufacturer: GenuineIntel                             
        ID: FB 06 00 00 01 03 00 00                            
        Signature: Type 0, Family 6, Model 15, Stepping 11     
        Flags:                 
                FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)              
                CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)           
                APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)         
        Version: Intel Xeon    
        Voltage: 1.2 V         
        External Clock: 266 MHz                                
        Max Speed: 3733 MHz    
        Current Speed: 2000 MHz                                
        Status: Populated, Enabled                             
        Upgrade: ZIF Socket    
        L1 Cache Handle: 0x0009                                
        L2 Cache Handle: 0x000A                                
        L3 Cache Handle: Not Provided                          
        Serial Number: Not Specified                           
        Asset Tag: Not Specified                               
        Part Number: Not Specified
```

Based on `Max Speed`, I would guess that it is a [Xeon 5080](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Xeon_microprocessors#.22Dempsey.22_.2865_nm.29) CPU. However, according to `/proc/cpuinfo`, it is [Xeon E5335](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Xeon_microprocessors#.22Clovertown.22_.2865_nm.29):

```
# grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5335  @ 2.00GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5335  @ 2.00GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5335  @ 2.00GHz
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5335  @ 2.00GHz
#
```

When I check the flags/features listed in `/proc/cpuinfo`, then it shows `ssse3`, which is supported in [Xeon 5080](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Xeon_microprocessors#.22Dempsey.22_.2865_nm.29) and not in [Xeon E5335](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Xeon_microprocessors#.22Clovertown.22_.2865_nm.29).
How does `/proc/cpuinfo` detect the CPU model?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On x86, it uses the [`CPUID` “Processor Brand String”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX.3D80000002h.2C80000003h.2C80000004h:_Processor_Brand_String) feature, where supported. Thus in your case it’s the CPU itself which is returning the “Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5335  @ 2.00GHz“ string. This corresponds to the `dmidecode` output: `ID: FB 06 00 00 01 03 00 00` matches a 06FB CPUID, *i.e.* [E5335](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Xeon/Intel-Xeon%20E5335%20-%20HH80563QJ0418M%20(BX80563E5335A%20-%20BX80563E5335P).html) (a [5080](http://www.cpu-world.com/sspec/SL/SL968.html) would have a 0F64 CPUID).

You can see the kernel implementation in [`arch/x86/kernel/cpu/common.c`’s `get_model_name` function](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14.13/source/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/common.c#L641).

The Xeon E5335 is a Clovertown CPU, which [does support SSSE3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xeon#Clovertown).

Comment: Thanks! However, this makes me wonder, where does this `Max Speed: 3733 MHz` come from seen in the output of `dmidecode`?

Comment: Back in the Pentium 4 and Core days, DMI tables commonly listed the maximum supported CPU speed of the motherboard, not the maximum Turbo speed of the CPU (which didn’t exist); that could explain what you’re seeing here. With its 1066MHz FSB, I’m not sure a 5080 could even be configured to run at exactly 2GHz...

Comment: That could be true in this case as well because according to [Wikipedia list of Intel Xeon microprocessors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Xeon_microprocessors) article, the highest frequency Xeon CPU for LGA 771 socket is Xeon 5080 which operates at 3733 MHz.